# How to run a method into background in iOS

Tags: multithreading

I'm have a method called "uploadImage". this my method will upload images to my server.
But, when I back to other view, the "uploadImage" method not run. I want the "uploadImage" method alway run until done !

So, how i can resolve it.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can put that method in a Background Queue using GCD.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                                        [self uploadImage:params];
                                    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; 
                                });
I'm using this code, but not ok.

Comment: what do you mean with "not ok"? some more details would be nice. what are you using NSRunLoop for? Apple Docs: Warning: "The NSRunLoop class is generally not considered to be thread-safe and its methods should only be called within the context of the current thread. You should never try to call the methods of an NSRunLoop object running in a different thread, as doing so might cause unexpected results."

Answer (score 0):

Look at NSOperationQue or NSThread, NSOperationQue is probable the better more modern way yo go, especially if you have a number of uploadImages that are determined at runtime.